# Insert column with the same string in all lines

Tags: awk, sed

I have this file

```
mean.cel sample.cel
1  2
3  4
```

I would like to insert a column with a partial name of the header of the second column

This will be the expected result

```
mean.cel newcolumn sample.cel
1  sample 2
3  sample 4
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say...

```
$ awk 'NR==1{print $1, "new column", $2; next} {print $1, "sample", $2}' file
mean.cel new column sample.cel
1 sample 2
3 sample 4
```

To make it more robust, allowing you to have multiple fields (not just 2), we can say:

```
awk '{$1 = $1 OFS (NR==1?"new column":"sample")} 1' file
```

The idea here is to append a new value to the 1st field. By playing with `NR` we switch the behaviour depending on being in the 1st line or in the rest of them.

Comment: Thanks. thats works!. How Can i do the same?, but in multiple files (let's say in recursive way)

Comment: Does what it says on the tin, so +1. I'd probably use `{ $1 = $1 OFS "sample" } 1` to make it work for an arbitrary number of columns, though.

Comment: @Wintermute interesting, I took your idea and tweaked it a little to do something a bit fancy: `{$1 = $1 OFS (NR==1?"new column":"sample")} 1`. Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '1 {s/ / NewColumn /;b;}
s/ / Sample /' YourFile
```

- based on your sample and using space as separator